# Nested polygon count and shapefile query

Tags: shapefile, polygon, query

[image]I have attached a subset of shapefile polygons with a number of nested polygons. Wondering

1. How would I go about writing a query to figure out how many such nested polygons exists in one shapefile.
2. I have written a skeleton query, looking for some guidance on this. I want to compare the area of the three polygons and code it in the parent query such that I get the polygon with the largest area.

```sql
DECLARE @geoPoint geography; 
DECLARE @geog1 geography;  
DECLARE @geog2 geography; 
DECLARE @geog3 geography; 
SET @geoPoint = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(long lat)', 4326);

----Parent query--------------
SELECT * from [GISTable]  where geog.STContains(@geoPoint) = 1

----poly big polygon --------------
SELECT @geog1 = geog FROM [GISTable] WHERE id = 1;  
SELECT @geog1.STArea();  

----poly medium polygon  --------------
SELECT @geog2 = geog FROM [GISTable] WHERE id = 2;  
SELECT @geog2.STArea();  

----poly small polygon --------------
SELECT @geog3 = geog FROM [GISTable] WHERE id = 3;  
SELECT @geog3.STArea();
```

Comment: Query in what language?

Comment: i wrote this in tsql.

Comment: Providing a screen shot of your data, might help show what you mean by nested.

Comment: Klewis,I have added an image of the polygons. Notice that in the within the highlighted "big polygon" there are 4 small polygons. Currently when i run the parent query and if the point is within any one of the 4 small polygons, i get multiple results. My logic when a point is in one of the smaller polygons to compare the area and return the big polygon.

Comment: Also to my first question, as you can see there are a multitude of such polygons, Is there a way using sql i can identify such nested polygons or if it  is easier to identify then using qgis and subsequently merge the smaller ones into the bigger polygon(if that can be done). The whole question surround, given a point in a polygon, i should get one and only one result.

Comment: When you refer to 'nested', are you referring to the holes (un highlighted areas completely within), or the other parts of polygons that overlap?

Comment: Nested refers to the small ones that are un-highlighted within the bigger polygon